# Algorithm to find liars and truthtellers

Tags: algorithms

This is the exercise 2.18 from Introduction to Bioalgoritms of Neil Jones. It says:

> We have a mix of 100 participants: some are honest while others are not. The honest ones always tell the truth, but the deceitful ones sometimes tell the truth and sometimes lie. You can ask any participant the following question about any other participant: “Participant Y, is Participant X honest?” Participant Y will answer with either “yes”or “no.” Design an algorithm that, with no more than 198 questions, would allow you to ﬁgure out which of the 100 participants are honest. It is known that there are more honest than dishonest participants.

Comment: What are your own thoughts on the riddle? We won't solve it for you. Let me suggest you try the riddle with 100 replaced by a smaller number, perhaps 2 or 3. The number of questions should presumably be at most 2 or 6.

Comment: The case of 2 participants is particularly simple, and I encourage you to try it out. Perhaps you can even do better than 2 questions.

Comment: Suppose we have participant A and participant B .  When I ask A , he says B is honest, when I ask B, he says A is honest  .  So, both are honests or dishonet. If I ask again, and someone change the answer , well , both are dishonests,   but what if are the same ? I can't say they are honests, even if I have asked 100 times, maybe at 101 they will change the answer. I'm really confused here

Comment: Try to use the fact that there are more honest than dishonest professors. I suggest thinking about this riddle for a few more days before coming back here.

Comment: This appears to be copied from *An Introduction to Bioinformatics Algorithms*, or from Q1 of [a homework assignment from Simpson College's CmSc 250](http://faculty.simpson.edu/lydia.sinapova/www/cmsc250/cmsc250-10/Assignments/HW_Problems.doc).   Please provide proper attribution for the source of this material.  Don't just copy-paste from another source without attribution; that constitutes plagiarism, which isn't welcome here.  See http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.

Answer (score -1):

The problem cannot be solved at all. It is possible that they are all honest, and therefore always say that everyone else is honest. Or they could all be liars, and in order not to be found out, the also all say that everyone else is honest. If everyone says that everyone is honest, you know they are all honest or all liars, but you don't know which one.

There was an attempt at some help which went badly wrong: "There are more honest than dishonest professors". Since we don't know whether there are any professors among the participants, this hint is useless. Had we been told "there are more honest than dishonest professors among the participants", that would have meant there is at least one honest participant, making the scenario of all dishonest participants impossible. The poster might have meant "there are more honest than dishonest participants", which would have been a stronger hint.

Comment: Q: `100 participants…It is known that there are more honest than dishonest participants` A: `they could all be liars` - no; and the ambiguity about _professors_ (from said large department or globally) might arise from the homework _not_ linked by Astrid A. Olave H.

Answer (score -1):

Just Pick a single man and ask the rest of the 99 person a single question I.e., raise your hands it this person is a truthteller. If he he is a truthteller then the majority answer will be in his favour as the majority are truth tellers. But if by any chance the majority says he is a liar then remove him and start with another person. Try at last you find ha truthful person. As majority is of truth tellers the maximum question you need to ask to find a single true person is 48( do the math). once you have found the truth ask him about each person seperatly so the maximum question you will need to ask from that person will be 99. 99+48=147 you found who is truthful and who is a liar in just 147 questions

Comment: I think we are aiming for  198 questions *in total*.

Comment: In particular, if the first two people you choose are liars, you've already used up your 198 questions.